# Background image is squashed on iPhone 4 because it uses 2x images shared with iPhone 5 and 6. Any fix?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm creating an app with a patterned background. So i laid down a UIimageview behind my button & label etc. and set the image to a background image.

Now here's the problem:

When played on an iPhone 4, the image is squashed down. This is because the iphone 4 uses 2x images. However, if i change the image to the correct dimensions for the 4, the background on the iPhone 5 and 6 become squashed, because the 4's display is fatter than the 5 and 6.

What i am asking: is there a way to have the iPhone 4 choose from a different background image source that isn't 2x? OR is there a way to have each phone choose the perfect display?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `xcassets` (if you aren't, you should), select your image and choose these settings. It will allow you to choose different images for the different aspect ratios.

[image]

Another alternative is to set the image view's `contentMode` to `aspectFill`, that way the image will be scaled to fill the imageView while keeping the aspect ratio.